# onPostExecute in anko doAsync

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, anko

I know there are two methods available to do **AsyncTask** in **Anko library**.

1. doAsync()
2. doAsyncResult()

My question is both the above methods have `onComplete()` method. In both method's `onComplete()` there is no trace of result like `AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`.

**Example**:

```
        doAsync {
            sdkServiceFactory.initSDKService()
            onComplete { Log.d("Controller", "Sdk Connected") }
        }

   val result = doAsyncResult {
                  onComplete { Log.d("Controller", "Sdk Connected") }
                  sdkServiceFactory.initSDKService()
                }.get()
```

In either method, I can get only the completed callback not the result. What are the similar methods available in **Anko library** for **AsyncTask.onPreExecute()** and **AsyncTask.onPostExecute()**.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/181#issuecomment-218843857

Answer (score 6, accepted):

doAsync is used to execute code on a different thread, but does not return anything to the main thread when finished.

doAsyncResult is used to perform an activity on a separate thread, and the execute an operation on the main thread after completing execution on the separate thread.

To push anything to the main thread, add a new block with

```html
uiThread {
        //write you code here
    }
```

in it.

Or better yet, create the method that you want to run asynchronously as a function with a return value. Then pass the method in to the doAsync call. To quote an example:

```html
 val longRunningTask: (AnkoAsyncContext<ListView>.() -> ArrayList<String>) = {
                ::doAnIntensiveActivity.invoke()
            }
 val f : Future<ArrayList<String>> = doAsyncResult(null, longRunningTask)
```